# Replacement for CJK's \Unicode macro

Tags: luatex, unicode

I need a replacement for the `\Unicode` macro from CJK. It takes two decimal numbers as arguments and inserts `#1*256 + #2` into the token stream (or something like that; it's a way to write Unicode characters by code like `&#65;` in XML).

That should be possible with a tiny bit of lua code. Any pointers?

Comment: Would `\char\numexpr#1*256+#2\relax` suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, a definition such as

```
\newcommand{\Unicode}[2]{\char\numexpr#1*256+#2\relax}
```

should be what you need.